# How to ensure the data type precision remains the same after importing data with MySQL plugin?

Tags: mysql, datetime-format, dolphindb

When importing data of type DATETIME from MySQL with DolphinDB MySQL plugin, I found that the milliseconds were discarded. For example, 2023.12.12 09:12:01 500 was changed to 2023.12.12 09:12:01.

I have tried to solve this problem with the following script:

```
db=database("dfs://test6", VALUE, `ag2306`fu2305`fu2309)
def replaceTable(mutable t){return t.replaceColumn!(`datetime,nanotimestamp(t[`datetime]))}
t=mysql::loadEx(conn, db, "tb",`symbol, "SELECT * FROM dbtickdata LIMIT 100",,,,replaceTable)
```

However, the result is still not what I expected, even though the data type has been replaced. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that the MySQL plugin parses the MySQL’s DATETIME into the DolphinDB’s DATETIME, which doesn’t support a higher precision than seconds. So when you pass a table to the *transform* of `mysql::loadEx`, the time type of its column has already been DolphinDB’s DATETIME. The trailing fractional seconds part in higher precision has been discarded.

To solve this problem, refer to the following steps:

1. use `mysql::extractSchema` to get the schema of the MySQL table;
2. update the column of type DATETIME to NANOTIMESTAMP in the schema
   table;
3. pass the schema table to the schema of `mysql::loadEx`.